# Weird powerline symbol background in iterm2

Tags: neovim, iterm2

I am experiencing a weird background color of powerline symbol in **iterm2**, it doesn't match with that of status bar. however, in **alacritty**, the background color are matched.

In iterm2:

[image: status bar in iterm2]

In alacritty:

[image: status bar in alacritty]

In the screenshot, I am using

- macos 10.15.6
- neovim 0.5.0 nightly with lightline plugin
- alacritty v0.5
- iterm2 v3.4.0beta6
- font is patched with *nerd-font-patcher*

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by sliding minimum constrast bar in iterm2 profile.

Comment: could you pls clarify the reason why?

Comment: Well, it is an answer. I fixed your post to look better, and tried to remove it from the VLQ queue.